# Pure HTML5/JS/JSON project. How to get base URL?

Tags: javascript, json, html, web

Suppose we start pure HTML5/JS/JSON application. So UI in browser, user interaction handled by JS, data fetching/storing in AJAX.

By **pure** I understand that you don't *preprocess* any `.html`, `.js`, `.css` files (except a few configs) with any view template engine, scriplets, etc. Just pass as static resources.

To be maintainable project resources structured in hierarchy with several levels by `/` in URLs (and directories in file storage).

We don't want to inline any specific URLs in our code.

How to define URLs in HTML/JS so project can be moved without changes in `.html`, `.js` files (except a few config files)?

I see problems in following HTML code:

```
<script src=".../js/...">
<style src=".../css/...">
<image src=".../img/...">
```

and in following JS code:

```
ajax('GET', 'http://.../ajax/...');
```

When you preprocess files you can use:

```
<script src="${base}/js/...">
<style src="${base}/css/...">
<image src="${base}/img/...">

ajax('GET', '${base}/ajax/...');
```

Note that relative paths (like `../../ajax/data.json` to get data from `/html/data/list.html`) may not work in included JS code (as you don't know at which level of HTML this inclusion happen, so don't know how much strip `/`).

Or pure HTML 5 project is myth?

One time preprocessor pass for inserting concrete IP/DN and context URL part resolve issue, but deploy in that case deploy far complicate then just copy files and set static content hosting...

Comment: You can use location object in javascript and dynamically compose URLs which you'll use in you ajax requests.
Also, you can dynamically include scripts, so you also be able to use location object.
The same is reasonable for stylesheets. But I have no ideas, what to do with images :(

Comment: Does the html files are always at the same level ? Why not using relative paths like `<script src="./js/...">`, where `./` always refer to the level where the html file is ?

Comment: @sebcap26 No, I ask with HTML files also at different levels... Seems that using name prefixes instead of `/` allow current dir trick, but in general seems you need preprocessing... So HTML/JS are limited low level languages and can't satisfy purposed requirements....

Comment: With HTML files at different levels, you won't be able to determine a unique base url common to each one. Maybe you can store it with  `localStorage`. Or, if your application is always at the root of the domain, you can use `<script src="/js/...">`.